# best sandbox type for staging environment

Tags: deployment, sandbox

Should it be full sandbox as suggested many times across [developer resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dev_lifecycle.meta/dev_lifecycle/plan_sandbox_features.htm).
Or would you agree with [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/12/salesforce1-enterprise-environment-management.html) and utilise partial copy to gain frequent refresh?

Comment: It would be hard to give an answer that is not opinion-based, but if you have other systems interacting with salesforce that store sfids, I would suggest using at least a partial copy sandbox so you can properly test those system interactions.

Comment: thanks martin. I wanted to start discussion. I know what the study guide says and review board would like to hear but I find it silly that people study the answers just to get another badge. I think the other article has a valid point. If your release cycles are more frequent than the sandbox refresh you may have valid point to use partial copy.  What other pros would you point and is it common practice to use partial instead of full. Do you see companies buying 2 full copy sandboxes for QA & staging? really?

Comment: In terms of release cycles, the ideal method from a traditional software development perspective would be to make all changes in a test environment and then deploy to a live system once the changes have been validated.

Comment: Salesforce is about as far as you can get from the concept of an immutable server, and even if you are conservative with giving out org-modifying permissions, there always seems to be drift between the production and sandbox environments. The frequency of your sandbox refreshes isn't as much determined by how often disciplined developers release changes from a sandbox into production as it is a factor of the magnitude of changes that people make directly in production.

Comment: As for other reasons to use a partial sandbox over a full sandbox, to be honest, the only differences are price, refresh period, and amount of data copied. If the refresh period isn't the determining factor, it would have to be up to each company's discretion whether they feel having full copy sandboxes is worth the expense.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be a full sandbox. Best option.

> The Staging Sandbox
>   The staging environment is the last environment in the development lifecycle before production.  The staging sandbox is a Full sandbox that contains all data and metadata that’s in production—it’s a full replica of production that enables you to perform real-world testing and catch any data-dependent issues that affect the behavior of the app. Use the staging environment to perform a test deployment and to perform final regression testing—run all tests and make sure that the deployment is successful. This task is equivalent to a validation-only deployment to production.

If you check the [Developer Life Cycle](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_development_lifecycle.pdf) and examine the 'Staging' sandbox you will find the full description on the type of sandbox you need to use.

Comment: Indeed, the staging is for end user testing and should be exactly same as production. And the refresh would not be that frequent, if the release management is handled properly.